# Problem bundling a mac application

Tags: macos, bundle, intel, launch

I'm trying to make a mac app bundle. It is bundled around a shell file. The structure is like this:

```
App
    Contents
        Info.plist
            App.command
        MacOS
        Resources
            App.icns
```

However, when I double click on the app bundle, it shows the following prompt:

`To open classroom.command, you need to install Rosetta. Would you like to install it now?`

It seems that my app bundle is not intel-based. But it doesn't make sense. Shell scripts have nothing to do with what platform it is right?

I verified it by getting info on the .app root folder. I can see that the "Kind" is "Application". Whereas on other launchable apps, I see that the "Kind" is "Application (Intel)". Is there something I missed from Info.plist?

Comment: I am such a noob in unix.

I forgot to tell what shell environment I am using. I added
`#!/bin/sh` to the top of the file and now it worked.

However, I am still quite curious. How is the line `#!/bin/sh` in the shell script related to thinking that this app is non-intel???

Comment: Thank you so much for adding that comment, it made me realise I had an extra space before #!/bin/bash. As you say, why the hell that makes OSX think the app is for PowerPC, I do not know. Also don't know how the hell I was supposed to be able to figure that out! Anyway, many many thanks, up voted your question.

Answer (score -1):

Rosetta is a piece of software through which PowerPC code can be run on an Intel Mac. Sow depending on your proccessor,OS you might need to instal it to run the application.

[here is the full explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/32084/what-is-rosetta-and-why-doesnt-snow-leopard-include-it-by-default)